# LISP Concatenate variable name with a string

Tags: lisp

I am wondering if i can do something like this in Lisp :

I need to declare n variables . So they will be n1,n2,n3...etc

```
(dotimes (i n) (setq (+ 'n i))
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Four errors: `(setq (+ 'n i))`: 1) `SETQ` does not declare variables, it sets them. 2) It also expects two arguments, not one. 3) `SETQ` is a special operator and expects a symbol as its first argument. You provided a list. 4) `+` expects numbers as arguments, not symbols.
Fifth error: `(dotimes (i n) (setq (+ 'n i))`: missing parentheses.

Comment: Practically speaking, why not declare an *n*-length vector? As Rainer suggests though, you might hold off on metaprogramming until you master normal programming :)

Answer (score 3):

Rainer Joswig pointed out in a comment that the code you've got doesn't work for what you're trying do, and explained why.  If you're trying to *declare* variables programmatically, you're going to need source code manipulation, which means that you need a macro.  In this case, it's pretty easy.  We can define a macro **with-indexed-vars** that takes  a symbol, a number, and a body, and expands to a **let** with the variables you'd expect, and that evaluates the body within that scope:

```
(defmacro with-indexed-vars ((var n) &body body)
  "Evalutes BODY within a lexical environment that has X1...XN
declared as variables by LET.  For instance

    (with-indexed-vars (x 5)
      (list x1 x2 x3 x4 x5))

expands to 

    (LET (X1 X2 X3 X4 X5)
      (LIST X1 X2 X3 X4 X5))

The symbols naming the variables declared by the LET are interned
into the same package as VAR.  All the variables are initialized
to NIL by LET."
  (let ((name (symbol-name var)))
    `(let ,(loop for i from 1 to n
              collecting (intern (concatenate 'string name (write-to-string i))
                                 (symbol-package var)))
       ,@body)))
```

Then, we can use it like this:

```
(with-indexed-vars (n 4)
  (setq n3 "three")
  (setq n4 4)
  (list n4 n1 n3 n2))

;=> (4 NIL "three" NIL)
```

As Sean Allred notes in a comment, this is sort of an advanced topic for beginning Lisp programming.  If you know that you need *n* value cells, you might as well just use a vector and **aref** to access the values:

```
(let ((ns (make-array 4 :initial-element nil)))
  (setf (aref ns 2) "three")
  (setf (aref ns 3) 4)
  ns)

;=> #(NIL NIL "three" 4)
```